# Powershell Error Handling while processing a list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to clean up the active directory ahead of the Skype 4 Business deployment, which requires correcting sip addressing. After doing some poking around I found other problems, including unusual emails formats, which I need to account for. I was asked to roll out the changes, but due to an error `Get-CsAdUser -Identity $line.Name` when the user can't be found. However this means they are taking a slot from a user who could be changed, as written at this time.

I would like it if the error occurs increase `$line`, do not increment `$limiter`, and try again with the next person on the list. I'm still reading how to use `try/catch` and `return` but I'm still unsure how to structure these to allow script to process another 25 people every run.

```
## Collect User Base
Get-CsAdUser  -OU "OU=..." -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}  | Where-Object{$_.UserAccountControl -notmatch "AccountDisabled"}| Select Name, WindowsEmailAddress, SipAddress|Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path c:\tmp\EmailSIP_$d.csv
$csv = Import-csv c:\tmp\EmailSIP_$d.csv

## Change 25 users
$first = $True
$limiter = 0
foreach ($line in $csv){
    $goodsip =  -join ("sip:", $line.WindowsEmailAddress)
    $sipcheck = ($goodsip -ne $line.SipAddress) #If SIP not as expected then "proceed with change is TRUE"
    $otherchecks #If no other AD fields are formatted 'incorrectly' will "proceed with change be True"
    If ($emailcheck -And $otherchecks){
        If ($first) {
            Write-Output (-join ("Name, WindowsEmailAddress, old-SipAddress, new-SipAddress"))|Out-File -Append c:\tmp\Changed_EmailSIP_$d.txt
            $first = $False}
        If ($limiter -lt 25){
            Write-Output (-join ($line.Name,", ", $line.WindowsEmailAddress,", ", $line.SipAddress,", ", $goodsip))|Out-File -Append c:\tmp\Changed_EmailSIP_$d.txt
#Errors Generated in following line for some $line.NAMES
        Get-CsAdUser -Identity $line.Name|Set-CsUser -SipAddress $goodsip -ErrorAction Ignore  -whatif 
        $limiter++}
    If ($limiter -ge 25){break}  #exit loop if 25 changes
    }  #end of IF Email and Sip
}  #end of foreach
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Get-CsAdUser : Management object not found for identity "person1".
At line:3 char:1
+ Get-CsAdUser -Identity $line.Name|Set-CsUser -SipAddress $goodsip -wh ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (person1:UserIdParameter) [Get-CsAdUser], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Identity,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.Cmdlets.GetAdUserCmdlet
```

Comment: pass `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-CsAdUser` and wrap that line in a `try { }` block, then in your `catch { }` block after it, use `continue` to skip to the next iteration of your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @TheIcorrigible for your comment.

The working code:

```
foreach ($line in $csv){
$goodsip =  -join ("sip:", $line.WindowsEmailAddress)
$sipcheck = ($goodsip -ne $line.SipAddress)
$otherchecks
If ($emailcheck -And $otherchecks){
    If ($limiter -lt 25){
        try{
            Get-CsAdUser -Identity $line.Name -ErrorAction Stop|Set-CsUser -SipAddress $goodsip -whatif
            If ($first) {
                Write-Output (-join ("Name, WindowsEmailAddress, old-SipAddress, new-SipAddress"))|Out-File -Append c:\tmp\Changed_EmailSIP_$d.txt
                $first = $False}
            Write-Output (-join ($line.Name,", ", $line.WindowsEmailAddress,", ", $line.SipAddress,", ", $goodsip))|Out-File -Append c:\tmp\Changed_EmailSIP_$d.txt
            $limiter++}
        catch{continue}
        }
    If ($limiter -ge 25){break}
    }
}
```